# 301 rewrite will not redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

Hi looking for some help, i have a product link 
iphone%20-5c-replacement-button

i have removed the blank space and i am trying to set up a "301 rewriterule" to the new page.

i tried this

```
RewriteRule ^iphone%20-5c-replacement-button$ /iphone-5c-replacement-button [R=301,L]
```

But this did not work, so i tried this way

```
Redirect 301 "/iphone -5c-replacement-button" http://www.mysite.co.uk/iphone-5c-replacement-button
```

i also tried

```
Redirect 301 "/iphone -5c-replacement-button" "http://www.mysite.co.uk/iphone-5c-replacement-button"
```

can anyone please help with this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match the space %20 using **\s** char in RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^iphone\s-5c-replacement-button$ /iphone-5c-replacement-button [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You are a star my friend. ive been trying to sort this out for hours :)